# how to grant write permissions to an web api application in IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

I simply have a web api application on IIS server that simply writes to text file on C:\FileStorage\test.txt however when I call this webservice I get the internal 500 error, after expanding the error,I get the following error, how do I grant write access to this web service on IIS server?

```
"ExceptionMessage": "Access to the path 'C:\\FileStorage\\test.txt' is denied.",
"ExceptionType": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Grant permissions for that folder to the application pool.  So you'd go to the C:\FileStorage folder in Windows and edit permissions, and add IIS APPPOOL\appPoolNameHere as a user, then give it full permissions.

Hope that helps.

*EDIT*

Step by Step Instructions...

-Open Windows Explorer

-Browse to your folder

-Right click the folder and go to Properties

-On the Security tab click Edit

-Click Add

-Under Locations, make sure it is pointing at your local machine, not a domain

-For the object name, enter below but replace MyAppPool with the name of your application pool...

IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool

-Set the permissions to Full, or just add Write, or whatever you need.

Comment: would you please add little more details?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  You know how to add permissions to a folder for a user right?  You do the exact same thing, but you add it for the application pool.

Comment: the problem is I dont know how exactly how to add permission to a folder or IIS

Comment: My question is, how do you determine the name of your app pool? Is there a default name that can be used if you haven't specifically set one up?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon To determine the app pool, you need to go to IIS, click on your website and then click on Basic Settings. The app pool should be displayed there.

Comment: @Jim I am facing the same issue but when trying to access a network shared folder. Do you have any solution for this scenario?

Comment: Maybe it is interesant for someone more: the default name is IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Answer (score 0):

or you can repalce APPPOOL to the name of your server or computer and with the `IIS_ISURS`. 
example:

```
yourserver\IIS_IUSRS
```

See this Screen Shot

[image: screenshot]