# 404 iis 10 error when call hosted ASP.NET Core 6 Web API from another computer

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have created a standard ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in Visual Studio 2022, published it, and hosted it on a server. While the API works correctly on the server at `{serverIP}/{method}`, when I try to call it from my computer using the same URL, I get an HTTP 404 error:

> File or directory not found

Here is my `web.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\testApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You probably have an authentication issue.  The client that is used where code works has the permission to access to the file, while client the give 404 does not have access to the file.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks so much! How can i check this? How get permission to my api for another client? I never see it in manual. Also i have react app on another ip and it work good, it work with cloud flare and people can see it in browser. I want connect this site and my app, but api don't work if called not locally

Comment: see: [IIS site cannot access local client drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637683/iis-site-cannot-access-local-client-drive)

Comment: @Luuk for IIS_IUSRS and testApi i get full permissions, but it doesn't help(

Comment: Then you might need: [Using Failed Request Tracing Rules to Troubleshoot Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr), which is a too difficult subject (for me) to explain in an answer (or comment )

Comment: This error indicates that the core application hosting is not working at all, are there other  sites on this same server? What are the port bindings?

Comment: Before wasting your time on the non-existent permission issue, check what site bindings you set, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, yes, i have react app and it work good, my core application work good on my server, but call from another get 404. I don't bindings nothing